# Difference between query's arguments passed by execute or by string %s

Tags: python, string, exception, arguments, psql

I was advised to use the following piece of code:

```
query = 'Select "logtext" from log where jobid = %s;'
cursorErrorData.execute(query, str(row[0]))
```

Instead of using this:

```
query = 'Select "logtext" from log where jobid = %s;' % str(row[0])
cursorErrorData.execute(query)
```

I have used the first example and it works fine, but in this example it crashes.

The data that str(row[0]) retrieve is the following:

```
3090
```

And this is the exception:

> > not all arguments converted during string formatting

****Could someone explain to me the difference between both methods and why in this particular case, I can't use it?****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `execute` should be a sequence of arguments. If you supply `str(row[0])`, then it is interpreted as a sequence, rather than a single argument. (A string is a sequence of characters.)

Wrap it in a tuple.

```
cursorErrorData.execute(query, (str(row[0]),))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a **tuple** in the second parameter for `cursor.execute`.

**Ex:**

```
query = 'Select "logtext" from log where jobid = %s;'
cursorErrorData.execute(query, (str(row[0],))    #-->tuple (str(row[0],)
```